# How to change chapter numbers manually

Tags: numbering, chapters

I found a little template on the internet. If I write all the chapters in one `.tex` file, the chapter number increments automatically. But I want to put each chapter `.tex` file in a separate folder. The problem is that the chapter numbers are reset to 1 on each chapter.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=1.5cm, a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newlength\ChapWd %logo
\settowidth\ChapWd{\huge\chaptertitlename}%logo

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,122}%logo

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filcenter\sffamily} %texte du titre chapitre
  {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    {
    \node[fill=myblue,font=\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east,minimum size=\ChapWd] 
      at ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=-15pt]current page.north east) 
      (numb) {\thechapter};
    \node[rotate=90,anchor=south,inner sep=0pt,font=\huge\color{myblue}] at (numb.west) {Chapter}; %logo
    }
  }{0pt}{\fontsize{33}{40}\selectfont\color{myblue}#1}[\vskip10pt\Large***]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{50pt}{10pt} %logo


\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\ttl@printlist}{\endgroup}{{\noindent\color{myblue}\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\vskip30pt\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\DoPToC{
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\noindent{\color{myblue}\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\par\medskip}%
}

\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize\itshape}

\begin{document}
\chapter{\textbf{Contexte & objectifs}}
\DoPToC
\section{A test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\section{Yet another test section}
```

Comment: you can have the chapters in separate files without resetting the number. But do you want then in separate pdf files with separate page counts also starting from 1 (which this example will give you)

Comment: if you just want to change the chapter number but `\setcounter{chapter}{5}` if you want the first `\chapter` to make chapter 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two options. In either case you need to create a *master document* in the root folder:

```
PROJECT_ROOT
  +-master.tex
  +-Chapter1
  |  \-chapter.tex
  \-Chapter2
     \-chapter.tex
```

## classic `\include{chapter.tex}`

in your master document you simply use `\include{chapter.tex}`

```
\documentclass{article}
%% preamble here
\begin{document}
  \include{Chapter1/chapter.tex}
  \include{Chapter2/chapter.tex}
\end{document}
```

In your `chapter.tex` you leave out anything before (and including) `\begin{document}` and also the final `\end{document}`

The disadvantage is that you cannot compile the chapters separately from their folder unless you create a "fake master" in the chapters directory.

The intended way to compile single chapters is the use of the `\includeonly{}` command that you add to the master.

## Use of the *subfiles* package

You change your master document to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% preamble here
\usepackage{subfiles}    
\begin{document}    
    \subfile{/subdir/name1.tex}
    \subfile{/subdir/name2.tex}
\end{document}
```

you change your subdocuments to this:

```
\documentclass[../master.tex]{subfiles}
 %% no preamble needed here, master files preamble is used.
 %% but you can override some commands here  eg. relative paths to images...
\begin{document}
  %% you capters content.
\end{document}
```

The advantage is that now you can coose to compile either the whole document from the root folder or any of  your chapters independent from the master (but then still with wrong numbering...) without the need of copying the preamble to the sub documents.

By the way:
You can apply the *subfile* recursively as long as any subfiles `\documentclass` declaration refers to the *master document*:

```
%% chapter.tex
\documentclass[../master.tex]{subfiles}images...
\begin{document}
  \sublile{section1/section.tex}
  \sublile{section2/section.tex}
\end{document}
```

---

```
%% section.tex
\documentclass[../../master.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
  %% you section content.
\end{document}
```